# Lifty | unresolved dependency: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4: not found

Tags: scala, lifty

I'm trying to add in plugins/build.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
  new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")
```

and then I get:

```
Exception: unresolved dependency: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4: not found
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

I'm doing as it says on http://lifty.github.com/Installing+The+Plugin.html

Comment: What version of SBT are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Lifty has not (yet) released an sbt-0.11.3 binary. (You can see this by visiting http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases).

Fortunately, sbt-0.11.2 plugins are binary compatible with sbt-0.11.3. Unfortunately, the syntax for using an 0.11.2 plugin from 0.11.3 [is a bit wonky](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/6QyKHMczG3I/JhGevpkyLS0J):

```
libraryDependencies += 
  Defaults.sbtPluginExtra( 
    "org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4", 
    "0.11.2", 
    "2.9.1" 
  )
```

While another alternative would be to use sbt-0.11.2, the [scala-tools.org shutdown](https://web.archive.org/web/20160603075055/http://blog.goodstuff.im/the-transition-of-scala-tools-org) has made that just slightly problematic. You'd have to use [the 0.11.3-2 launcher](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/3sE6DxS9t6E/45uMF_WmzPUJ), specify `sbt.version=0.11.2` in `project/build.properties`, and add the [Sonatype repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20190828230015/https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) as a resolver.