# Getting started with Lift and Lifty

Tags: scala, lift, sbt, lifty

I am trying to get started with the Lift framework, reading Lift in Action. I would like to follow along with the examples, but I immediately stumble into a problem with installing Lift. I know that there are various ways to get started easily with Lift, but I would like to use Lifty, as the book does, to be able to follow it.

The problem is that both Lifty and `sbt` (and Lift too!) have moved forward since the book was published. I installed `sbt` from the Typesafe repository for Ubuntu. Now I am stuck trying to install Lifty.

Following [Lifty documentation](http://lifty.github.com/Installing+The+Plugin.html) and [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010597/lifty-unresolved-dependency-org-liftylifty1-7-4-not-found) - due to the fact that Lifty has not released a binary for `sbt` 0.11.3 - I figured I should put the following in `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4")

libraryDependencies +=
  Defaults.sbtPluginExtra(
    "org.lifty" % "lifty" % "1.7.4",
    "0.11.2",
    "2.9.1"
  )
```

The latter is to tell `sbt` to use the Lifty plugin for sbt 0.11.2.

Now `sbt` seems to be able to download Lifty and starts correctly, but I do not have a `lifty` command. So when I do

```
lifty learn lift https://raw.github.com/Lifty/lifty/master/lifty-recipe/lifty.json
```

`sbt` complains:

```
[error] Not a valid key: lifty (similar: history)
[error] lifty learn lift https://raw.github.com/Lifty/lifty/master/lifty-recipe/lifty.json
[error]      ^
```

How should I install Lifty? Please note that I am new to Scala, sbt and Lift.

**EDIT**

I managed to install Lifty by downgrading to `sbt` 0.7.7. But then if I do

```
> lift create project-blank
> reload
> update
```

I get the error

```
[error] sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-webkit_2.9.1;2.3-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.testing#specs_2.9.1;1.6.6: not found
[info] == update ==
[error] Error running update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.liftweb#lift-webkit_2.9.1;2.3-RC3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.testing#specs_2.9.1;1.6.6: not found
```

Comment: I worked on LiA. I had hard time getting examples work with SBT 10+, use SBT 0.7.

Comment: see this http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45549&tstart=0

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how do I get to use an older version of sbt? Possibly while retaining the last version as installed from the Typesafe repository

Comment: I just downloaded the older jar, made some sort of shell script to run it. And added it to `$PATH`. All done.

Comment: @Nishant I have edited the question. Now it seems that I can get lifty, but when I try to install Lift itself, I get unresolved dependencies

Comment: Did you try to get ``"net.liftweb" % "lift-webkit_2.9.1" % "2.4"``?

Comment: I am not sure... but I remember there were painfully many tweaks requires to get through the book. :) Sadly, all this pissed me off so much that I moved to Play! (I finished the book like a snail). I guess you could give a try to different version like mhs suggested.

Comment: @Nishant Play 2 would be a nice option, but if I understand correctly it cannot be deployed on Tomcat currently. Can you confirm this? It is a requirement for me.

Comment: Play2 is really committing suicide by not releasing deployable war. They have a plan for it. [See this bug report.](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8-war-packaging), but I am not very optimistic. I am not sure if I am helping you, or confusing you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hate to break it to you, but lifty is gone. As of this writing, sbt's stable is 0.13.0. Looking at [sbt community repo](http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lifty/lifty/), the only version that was released was 1.7.4 for sbt 0.11.2.

The [official website](http://liftweb.net/getting_started) says:

> The [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/) is the most up-to-date resource to learn how to use Lift.

There's a section named [Creating a Lift Project from Scratch Using SBT](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#LiftFromScratch):

> ### Problem
>
> You want want to create a Lift web project from scratch without using the ZIP files provided on the official Lift website.
>
> ### Solution
>
> You will need to configure SBT and the Lift project yourself. Luckily, only five small files are needed.
> First, create an SBT plugin file at `project/plugins.sbt` (all filenames are given relative to the project root directory):
>
> ```
> addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.3.0")
> ```
>
> This file tells SBT that you will be using the xsbt-web-plugin.
>
> Next, create an SBT build file, build.sbt...

Unfortunately xsbt-web-plugin 0.3.0 is for sbt 0.12. So you have to either use sbt 0.12, or modify the instruction a bit. The latest [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) for sbt 0.13 is 0.4.2, so in `project/plugins.sbt` put:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.4.2")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
```

I was able to follow along with the rest of instructions on the page...
Eventually I got everything pulled in by sbt 0.13, and was able to start the container:

```
> container:start
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /foo/sbt-lift-test/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] jetty-8.1.7.v20120910
....
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 20, 2013 10:34:22 PM
```

Open `http://localhost:8080/` using the browser:

> Welcome, you now have a working Lift installation